# File Explorer hangs when trying access Mounted Azure File share on Windows 10 Desktop

Tags: network-drive, windows-10-desktop, azure-files

I mounted a **Azure File share** on to my desktop trying test connectivity. Everything worked awesome until I deleted the Azure File share in Subscription.

After my test, I deleted the test file share from **Azure subscription**. Then I continued working on my desktop where the deleted Fileshare was still mounted.

I was trying to navigate to some folder in file explorer and it just hangs. I tried to end the task from **Task Manager** and **Taskbar** vanished for 1-2 hours. Then I force rebooted my desktop. It came back fine. Then I wanted to get rid (**Unmap**) of the mounted Fileshare and same thing repeats again.

Can someone please help me get rid Or **UnMap a Network Drive** the Azure Fileshare off of my Desktop? Any command or something to **Unmap a Network Drive**? I tried **Net Use F:** no luck.

I have a deliverable that need to work on now and finish before Moring but my desktop is unusable at the minute.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**net use * /delete /y**
saved the day for me. Now I can resume my work.

Comment: Mine is worse, File explorer is hung, can't use the Start menu. Tried to close the File Explorer and my entire Windows Shell closed. Now can't access anything. I will NEVER use Azure file shares EVER again. Can't restart the shell, can't open Task manager from the 3-finger menu. Anybody got any clue?

Comment: I was in same situation as yours. 
I force rebooted my desktop, and opened powershell after the desktop came back and ran net use * /delete /y. That fixed my issue.

Comment: This answer is correct you should wait for more than 15 mins after executing this command for some case.

Answer (score 1):

I also could not get rid of the Azure share that no longer existed in Azure. Every time I tried to access it, the command (be it in Windows Explorer or command shell) would just hang. I could not even finish rebooting the machine - it would get stuck at the "Shutting down..." screen - powering down the machine was the only way to reboot. I could not install new storage software for Seagate portable hard drive - it would not recognize the drive (even though it was visible on Windows) until I resolved the Azure drive problem.

What worked for me was to do the following:

1. In the cmd.exe as administrator run this command: `mountvol /r`. According to Microsoft documentation it "Removes volume mount point directories and registry settings for volumes that are no longer in the system, preventing them from being automatically mounted and given their former volume mount point(s) when added back to the system."
2. Reboot - it got stuck rebooting again, had to press power
3. In the cmd.exe as administrator run this command: `net use <drive letter>: /delete /y`
4. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

`net use * /delete /y` helps for me, but only when I kill `explorer.exe` process manually

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases after a couple of reboots net use ?? /delete /y command works, I have had issues in which I have had to take a more drastic approach in "refreshing windows profile".

Regards

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).